# MVC PHP - A better way to simplify my linking

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, controller

I am looking for a way to create a solution to simplify my linking. On a site I am creating there will be multiple places (for example 15) where there will be a link to e.g. a privacy policy, and therefore when the URL to the policy changes I don't want to edit 15 different files, just change the URL in one place. I came up with this solution:

```
class PrivacyPolicy extends \Core\Controller
{

    const PrivacyPolicyUrl = 'privacy-policy';

    public function indexAction()
    {

        View::render('Privacy-policy/index.php', []);

    }
}
```

and when I want to link to the privacy policy I do it like this

```
<a href="<?=ROOT?><?=App\Controllers\PrivacyPolicy::PrivacyPolicyUrl?>">Privacy policy</a>
```

But i don't feel like it's it.

Note: I don't want to create a file with paths for each page, but define the URLs locally as shown above. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should implement some kind of a page menu/footer menu similar to [this one](https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial/blob/master/11-page-menu.md).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using Twig but I believe it will be helpful.